# How to find a workaround for latexdiff /latexdiff-vc on Windows on filenames containing spaces

Tags: perl, svn, latex, diff

I'm running latexdiff v 0.25 and when I attempt `latexdiff-vc --svn -r "myFile with spaces.tex"` I get the following command line output:

> Working on  myFile with spaces.tex svn: 'myFile' is not under version
>   control Running latexdiff 2 and only 2 non-option arguments required. 
>   Write latexdiff -h to get help Something went wrong in latexdiff.
>   Deleting myFile with spaces.tex and abort

I'm assuming it's a bug where the right filename isn't passed correctly to svn. The command runs fine on names w/o spaces.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: A suggestion for a viable alternative to LaTeX diff for version-control+ MS-word-like track changes would also be a good solution to this issue.

Comment: That seems very old. The latest version of latextdiff is 0.5 (http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/support/latexdiff/CHANGES). Are you unable to upgrade or at least try the latest version to see if this is fixed?

Comment: I updated using the MiKTeX package manager and I have latexdiff at 0.5 and latexdiff-vc at 0.25. Apparently that's the latest version. I looked at the .pl scrit and I suspect that it passes the wrong file name to svn.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this manually, you may be able to use the [8.3 file name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) that you can get on the command line using `dir /x`.

Comment: It worked when trying with OPTICA~2.tex (OPTICA~1.tex was the emacs backup). Although this gets the job done, my objective is to run latexdiff-vc from emacs which passes the full file name  of the current buffer to the command. Unless I find an emacs lisp function that converts regular filenames to 8.3 filenames I'm better off just not putting spaces in my .tex files.

Comment: @octi: not putting spaces in TeX file names is a good idea anyways. There is no portable way to use these names inside of other TeX files (for `\input`, for example).